# How big is the Cardano blockchain (now and in the future)?

Tags: blockchain

This may sound a naively simple question, but...

1. How big is the blockchian today?
2. How big is it likely to become in future?

I note that Daedalus' state directory on my machine is currently `~10.3G`.

Is it correct then to say that that's the "size of the chain" today?

For the second question, we could hypothesize a number of scenarios, like:
5 million Digital Identities are issued.
What impact is that likely to have on storage requirements of Daedalus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell how the network will grow into the future because of both varying usage and IOHK introducing new chain optimisations etc.. However we can work out the hypothetical maximum growth using the current chain parameters.

```
Max_Block_Size = 65536 bytes
Blocks_Per_Epoch = ~21000 
Epoch_Length = 5 days
```

So we could say a rough maximum chain size increase over an Epoch is `Max_Block_Size * Blocks_Per_Epoch` which comes out as `1.4155776 GB` per epoch or around `100 GB` per year.

Answer (score 7):

I'm only answering about the size for now: on one of the cardano nodes that I just checked some seconds ago

```
$ du -sh state-node-mainnet
9.4G
```

I can't say how fast it grows. I just look at it from time to time.

Comment: That is your size containing all the forks probably. Fresh sync of the mainnet is somewhere around 8.5GB.

Answer (score 6):

Compared to the size of the Bitcoin ledger, the size of the Cardano blockchain is smaller, as of ***November 06, 2023***. You can see the blockchain size if you look in the Daedalus wallet's folder on your SSD called *../wallet/chain/immutable*.

| Network | Blockchain size | Number of blocks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cardano | 147 GB | 9,511,839 |
| Bitcoin | 524 GB | 815,563 |

What will the size of the Cardano ledger be in 5 years period, for instance, is very difficult to say. It depends on the number of transactions in each block, the speed of formation of the ledger (we know it is Hydra's patrimony) and the total size of the transaction. Currently, the transaction size should not exceed **[16 KB](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/what-is-the-size-limit-of-transactions-metadata/4129#4129)**, including metadata.

However, in the Basho era, the Tx size could potentially be increased up to **256...512 KB**, due to the use of smart contracts and increased network throughput.